# Probability proof, sequence of sets: help with understanding the notation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

<strike>I'm having some trouble with the formatting here, so here's a screenshot of the problem we were given:</strike>

> Let $\{ A_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of sets. Show that
>   $$
> \lim\sup\limits_{n\to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_n} - \lim\inf\limits_{n\to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{A_n}
> = 
> \mathbf{1}_{\{\lim\sup_{n \to \infty} A_n \backslash \lim\inf_{n \to \infty} A_n\}}
> $$
>   and conclude that $A_n \to A$ if and only if $\mathbf {1}_{A_n}(\omega) \to \mathbf {1}_A(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. [$A \backslash B = A \cap B^c$.]

The problem is, that in the book from which the problem is taken from (*Probability Essentials* by Jean Jacod), we aren't given much help with understanding the notation. Earlier there is a proof where he defines $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} A_n$ but I have no idea what $\lim \sup_{n\to \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\ldots}$ could mean.

Is this some common notation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\mathbf 1}_{A_n}$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\{0,1\}$, defined by ${\mathbf 1}_{A_n} (\omega) = 1$ if $\omega \in A_n$, ${\mathbf 1}_{A_n} (\omega) = 0$ if $\omega \notin A_n$ (indicator function). $\lim \sup _{n \to \infty } {\mathbf 1}_{A_n }$ is defined pointwise: for each $\omega \in \Omega$, it is the $\lim \sup$ of the sequence of numbers ${\mathbf 1}_{A_n} (\omega)$, that is, $\lim \sup _{n \to \infty } {\mathbf 1}_{A_n }$ is a function on $\Omega$ defined pointwise by
$$
(\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\mathbf 1}_{A_n } )(\omega ) = \mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\mathbf 1}_{A_n } (\omega ) \,(\in \{ 0,1 \}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{1}_{A_n}$ is the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of reals ${a_n}$ then $\limsup a_n=\inf_{k\geq1}{\sup_{m\geq k}{a_m}}$, but I think the problem is that if you have a sequences of sets  ${A_n}$ then $\limsup A_n=\cap_{k\geq1}{\cup_{m\geq k}{A_m}}$ and $\limsup a_n=\cap_{k\geq1}{\cup_{m\geq k}{A_m}}$ and $\liminf A_n=\cup_{k\geq1}{\cap_{m\geq k}{A_m}}$, this is naturally if you consider a set $X$ and his power set $2^X$,in the power set you could define a order(not need to be a total order), for any $A,B\in 2^X$, $A\leq B$ if $A\subseteq B$, with this order the union is the sup and the intersection the inf. In real analysis or in calculus you could proof that a sequence of reals numbers converges ${a_n}$ if and only if $\limsup a_n=\liminf a_n$ and $\lim a_n=\liminf a_n$. You could give a notion of convergence of sets with the last proposition, a sequence ${A_n}$ of set converge if $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n$ and $\lim A_n=\liminf A_n$.